# using dll file in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, dll

I included the bin folder in my **MVC project** (*TestProj*), and added my own **dll** file (**testDll.dll**).
I am trying to access my dll file by writing:

```
using TestProj.testDll;
```

but it doesn't recognize my **testDll** file.

Comment: Did you add the `testDll.dll` file as a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add your `testDll.dll` file as a reference:

- Right click on `References` under your project
- Click `Add reference`
- Click `Browse` and look for your `testDll.dll` file

[image: Add reference]

Then, add the `using XXX;` (where `XXX` is a namespace present in your library) line in the files where you need to access your library members.

If you later want to update your library, just replace the `testDll.dll` file by the more recent.

Answer (score 1):

```
using Blah;
```

`Blah` is a namespace, not a DLL. It's just a convenience to save you the typing of the namespace when referencing the functions in the DLL.

What you want is to add the DLLs in the **references** of the project. Right-click *References* under your project (in the Project View) and choose *Add Reference*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to your assembly DLL.  Right-click your project's `References` in Soluction Explorer, select `Add Reference`, click the `Browse` tab, then select your library.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your project (testDll.dll) into references and try.

Answer (score 0):

Does your dll appear in your bin folder in the solution explorer window? Btw, you can only import the namespaces but not your dll with the using statement.